# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sortable is not a function after showing a modal

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm pretty new to using JQuery(and stackoverflow) so sorry for the messy code(and question).

I've been running into an issue with the sortable('serialize') from JQuery ui.

I'm making a connected sortable list where you can click on the second list, to open a modal that shows some more stuff.

The code to show the page and create the sortables work. Even the serialize seems to work.

The problem arises when I open the modal, close it again and then try to serialize. At that point I get the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sortable is not a function
```

To start I make two lists, with some added code to show the modal when you click on an item in list nr2

```
    @{int i = 0; int y = 0;}
<ul class="connectedSortable list-group" id="sortable1">
    @foreach (var item in Model.AvailibleSteps)
    {
        <!--Id needs a - or it returns an empty string-->
        <li class="list-group-item" id="Av-@(y)">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Name)
        </li>
        y++;
    }

</ul>
<ul class="connectedSortable list-group" id="sortable2">
    @foreach (var item in Model.ChosenSteps)
    {
        <li class="list-group-item" id="Ch-@(i)" style="cursor:pointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ChooseStepModal">
            <p class="StepIDText" style="display:none">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.ID)</p>
            <p class="PlanIDText" style="display:none">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.StepPlanID)</p>
            <p class="StepName">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Name)</p>
        </li>
        i++;
    }
</ul>
<input type="button" id="save" value="SAVE" />
```

after this messy pile of code I use jquery to fill the modal

```
        $('#ChooseStepModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var element = $(event.relatedTarget); // the tr that triggered the modal to show
        var myStapID = element.find('.StepIDText').text();
        var myPlanID = element.find('.PlanIDText').text();
        var myStapNaam = element.find('.StepName').text();
        var modal = $(this);
        $('popupHeader').html(myStepName);
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ChooseAssignments", "Home")',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { stepID: myStepID, planID: myPlanID },
            success: function (partialView) {

                $('#popup').html(partialView);
                $('#popup').show();
            }
        });
    });
```

and finally I also make the lists sortable, and set a quick alert to check if it's serialized

```
    $('#sortable1,#sortable2').sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        items: "li:not(.dontsort)"
    }).disableSelection();

    $('#save').click(function () {
        alert($('#sortable2').sortable('serialize'));
    });
```

when pressing the save button before opening the modal it responds with a result. But after opening and closing the model it gives the aforementioned type Error.

Comment: can you provide plunker?

Comment: Two things: 1 - the error shows a line number.  Which line in your code is triggering that error? (Please don't just include the line number, but indicate it in your code above as well so we know where).  2 - Please put your `sortable` code inside the context of when / how it's triggered.

Comment: making one now.

Comment: does your modal html include jquery or is using jquery.noConflict()?

Comment: @cale_b the line numbers don't reference to user created code. it references to the following lines:      at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (34:199)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.js:5201)
    at HTMLInputElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.1.1.js:5009)     where 34:199  seems to be nothing.

Comment: Sounds like you are somehow removing the `$('#sortable2')` element, I bet if you do `console.log($('#sortable2'));` youll see there is not matched element anymore and the log will look something like this http://prntscr.com/dy4co6

Comment: @DelightedD0D  logged it, it does change from:  [ul#sortable2.connectedSortable.list-group.col-md-6.ui-sortable]  to: [ul#sortable2.connectedSortable.list-group.col-md-6.ui-sortable, context: document, selector: "#sortable2"]  digging through the logs to see what i can find,  also to clarify, the clicking and dragging part still works, just the serialization fails i can still list all the id's for example

Comment: Can you post your rendered html?

Comment: @DelightedD0D  probably not exactly what you meant, still attempting to build a working plunkr example https://plnkr.co/edit/fHBGSo2gMG8P9MJM3hzo?p=preview  don't overthink it i'm probably being an idiot, also sorry for the dutch stuff

Comment: Hmm, your attempt there has jquery loaded twice `        
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
    then `<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>`, try removing one of those, that can definitely cause strange behaviour

Comment: Actually, you're loading it a third time here too `<div class="modal-body" id="popup"><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`  You only need one version of jquery and only need to include it once, i'd bet dollars to donuts that's your issue if that is your actual code

Comment: Yeah, see https://jsfiddle.net/d160vLqm/67/, if you ditch the multiple jquery includes, it seems to work as expected

Comment: @DelightedD0D Thanks a lot! i'm still checking why it includes those jquery instances(I can only find the reference to the online one, also wondering why I did that, seeing as jquery is in the scripts folder... but that is another matter entirely) Thanks for the help!  i'll be off to un-idiot my code :)